# Options not displaying in react-select dropdown, but can see the array looks good in console.log

Tags: react-select

I have an async api call (using axios) to fetch all my 'options' from the server. I can see the response coming in even modified the API to return the options with the "label" and "value" in the array.

I have tried using the  component which also did not work. I am not even trying to set the value yet, just want the list of options to display.
Have stripped the component to its bare minimum

Here is my complete component:

```
import Api from "../API/Api";

import Select from "react-select/async";

// so I have access to the AccessToken for any requests I need to send..
// Might want to 'catch' a 401 error and retry the submission, but lets first
// see if the form works properly
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

const GetSuppliers = () => {
  const [cookies] = useCookies("accessToken");
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [suppliers, setSuppliers] = useState([]);

  const askApi = async searchInput => {
    await Api.get("supplier", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer ".concat(cookies.accessToken)
      },
      params: {
        searchString: ""
      }
    }).then(response => {
      setSuppliers(response.data);
      return response.data;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    askApi();
  }, []);

  if (suppliers.length == 0) {
    return <div>Loading ... </div>;
  } else {
    console.log(suppliers);
    return (
      <div className="DropdownField">
        <Select cacheOptions options={suppliers} defaultOptions />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
export default GetSuppliers;
```

The console.log(suppliers); returns :

```
1: {value: 5609, label: "AAE02-01-AP", name: "Supplier name 2"}
2: {value: 6197, label: "AAG01-01-AP", name: "Supplier name 3"}
3: {value: 6402, label: "AAL01-01-AP", name: "Supplier name 4"}
4: {value: 6486, label: "AAN01-02-AP", name: "Supplier name 5"}
```

So I am expecting it to work. Where am I missing the plot?

Answer (score 0):

This was a rookie mistake (at least I am a rookie, so nobody can blame me).

During my original struggles I attempted the Async select, so the import was still reference the "Async" select.

Changed
`import Select from "react-select/async";`
to:
`import Select from "react-select";`

And voila, options showing!